# Ruby on rails - add more slider value selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slider

Currently I have a slider and drop down selection which are correlated to 4 possible values for oil recovery from a oil drill.  These values are p90, p50, p10, and fill_to_spill.  The user can select either the drop down p-value or move the slider along one of four possible values.

I wish to change the slider so that a larger number of slider positions can be selected.  For example 10 values with the first selection p(0) euqating to p90, the fifth equting to p50, ninth to p90 and the 10 to fill_to_spill.  The oil reserve esitmation between to be interpolated between these values.

To see the current application in Heroku got to http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/  Login as user = pmlc pw  pass1234 - select menu option "Drills" - select Drill-01, then select page "Investor Room"

Have pasted in current working code below.  Changing the slider value to max of 10 increases the number of options that can be selected via the slider.  On the slider any value selected after fifth selection leaves the p-value selected as blank and leaves the amount of oil as the "fill_to_spill" value.

drill.js.coffee

```
# Coffeescript to put slider in place
$('document').ready ->
  if $('#x_evaluation_assumption_params').length == 1
    select = $("#pvalue")
    slider = $("<div id='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider(
      min: 1
      max: 4
      range: "min"
      value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1
      slide: (event, ui) ->
        select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1
        $('#pvalue').trigger('change')
    )
    $("#pvalue").change ->
      slider.slider "value", @selectedIndex + 1

# (5) user changes the p-value selection for company resource estimation
#     can only work if current Discovery Target is a company resource estimation
$('document').ready ->
  $('#pvalue').change((event) ->
    # console.log('')
    # console.log("-5- User has changed p-value selection")
    drill_id = $('.form.assumption').attr('data-drillid')
    event.preventDefault()
     get_changed_p_values drill_id 
    )

# 05 (get_changed_p_values)
get_changed_p_values = (drill_id)-> 
    data = $('#x_evaluation_assumption_params').serialize()
    # console.log(" -05- in get_changed_p_values")
    # console.log data
    $.ajax
       url:"/drills/#{drill_id}/p_value_selected.json",
       type:"post"
       dataType: 'json'   # data type of response
       data: data
       success: (data,success,xhr)->
         # console.log(" -05- in get_changed_p_values - Success  ")
         displayAssumptions data
         calculateResult drill_id
       failure: (data,success,xhr)->
         console.log(" -05- in get_changed_p_values - Failure ")
         console.log data
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't appreciate how hard this would be. A third party is providing a vendor plugin to soleve this problem. Thanks - Pierre